# Как в Contact Form 7 изменить текст "The field is required"?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины, contact-form7

Помогите найти файл, в котором я смогу изменить текст, который указан на скриншоте (The field is required)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам сайт вот: https://evroflag.by/contacts.html

Как хоть называется этот файл, в котором лежит данный текст?

Comment: Это делается в админ панели, при редактировании формы есть вкладка "Messages". [Editing messages](https://contactform7.com/editing-messages/)

Comment: @Simon спасибо.